# How to use different analyzers in Elasticsearch depending on document to insert?

Tags: java, analyzer, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

My mapping has 4 string fields:

- "name"
- "info"
- "language"
- "genre"

and 4 custom analyzers:

- "english_custom_analyzer"
- "french_custom_analyzer"
- "spanish_custom_analyzer"
- "arabic_custom_analyzer"

I want to be able to specify the Analyzer to use when inserting the document using the language field. 
So If the language is English I want to use the English analyzer for documents field and if the language is French, I want to use the French Analayzer.

I tried to create an extra field called, "language_name_analyzer", populate that field with the analyzer name at insert time and set the analyzer name to "language_name_analyzer". But I get this error:

```
Cause: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Analyzer [language_name_analyzer] not found for field [datacontent_onair_title]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend to reconsider using this feature since it [has been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_mapping_changes.html#_analyzer_mappings) from the next major release of elasticsearch 2.0.

If you still want to use it, you need to specify the path to the `language_name_analyzer` field in the mapping:

```
{
    "type1" : {
        "_analyzer" : {
            "path" : "language_name_analyzer"
        },
        "properties": {
            //// your other fields
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a better solution to my problem? I can't be the only one who needs to support multiple language analyzers.

Comment: Yes, please check [Pitfalls of Mixing Languages](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/language-pitfalls.html) and the following sections of the definitive guide.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up create a separate index for each language and make a search query that searched across all indexes.